# Limit outgoing traffic per month

Tags: networking, traffic

I am looking at a virtual server tariff that has limited outgoing traffic for a month, with billing if the traffic is exceeded.

I would like to track the outgoing traffic automatically somehow, so that I can automatically can stop the service if the limit is being approached.

What tool can I use for this in Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, not knowing what the limit is or how good you are at scripting, here a suggestion.

Install `vnstat` - on Ubuntu that will automatically launch the accompanying demon process, which will immediately start monitoring the network (only for traffic stats, not content snooping).

You can look at it interactively, like so:

```
vnstat
Database updated: 2023-09-30 09:40:00

   enp0s31f6 since 2023-09-30

          rx:  7.85 GiB      tx:  93.23 MiB      total:  7.94 GiB

   monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       2023-09      7.85 GiB |   93.23 MiB |    7.94 GiB |   26.88 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated      8.02 GiB |   93.93 MiB |    8.11 GiB |

   daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
         today      7.85 GiB |   93.23 MiB |    7.94 GiB |    1.96 Mbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated     19.48 GiB |  231.46 MiB |   19.71 GiB |
```

You can also extract just the transferred data by using a command line switch & e.g. `awk`. In the example below we're looking at 111 MB transferred.

```
vnstat --oneline b |awk -F';' '{print $10/1024/1024}'
111.726
```

You could stick that into a shell-script that you run from cron e.g. every 5 minutes, and compare the transferred volume against your threshold, and have the script stop the service. Let's say you're allowed 5 G of outgoing traffic in a month.

```
#!/bin/bash
[  $(/usr/bin/vnstat --oneline b |/usr/bin/awk -F';' '{printf "%d", $10/1024/1024}') -gt 5000 ] && /usr/bin/systemctl stop service
```

Put that in `root`'s `crontab` and you're away laughing.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. The exact solution I want.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik - glad to hear it :)

Comment: `vnstat --alert 1 3 m rx 1 GiB -i eth0 || systemctl stop your-service` testing against exit code with [`--alert`](https://humdi.net/vnstat/man/vnstat.html) is more stable than using `awk` to parse its output format

Answer (score 1):

Grafana + Prometheus.

Setup these on any system/server and install the prometheus-node-exporter on your client system. Then in Grafana, you can write custom alerts when a certain threshold is reached, e.g. how much outgoing data has been flowing.

Comment: Thanks! But this needs me to go checking from my personal system constantly? I'd prefer to have automatic reaction, in case a DDOS or something like that causes rapid outflow of traffic when I am not looking. Also I am going to have only one server, but I can set up Grafana and Prometheus on it.

Comment: Alerts fire automatically and can send you an email. There are probably other hooks you can set, depending on the alert firing